# Increasing the width of an ellipse

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to write a program that will allow the user to adjust the width and height of an ellipse drawn on the form.
Here's my current code:

```
using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
{
    graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(colorDlg.Color), e.X, e.Y, x, y);
}
```

This code is written in the MouseMove event handler. The problem is that I want the user to be able to increase the width,x and the height,y by clicking a button or menustrip. The complication is that the eventhandlers for these controls don't accept the MouseEventArgs as an argument, therefore the compiler gives an error for e.X and e.Y.

Any useful ideas will be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I mean the other x and y(not e.X and e.Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private int x;
private int y;
private int width;
private int height;

private SomeForm()
{
    // Initialize ellipse position and size with some values
    ...
}

private void btnIncreaseWidth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    width += 5; // Increase width by 5 pixels
    Invalidate();
}

private void btnDecreaseWidth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    width -= 5; // Decrease width by 5 pixels
    Invalidate();
}

private void btnIncreaseHeight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    height += 5; // Increase height by 5 pixels
    Invalidate();
}

private void btnDecreaseHeight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    height -= 5; // Decrease height by 5 pixels
    Invalidate();
}

private void SomeForm_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(colorDlg.Color), x, y, width, height);
}
```

This assumes you have 4 buttons: two to increase/decrese width and two to increase/decrease height. Upon pressing the button, the respective dimension is changed and the form's content is invalidated (=> repainted).

Comment: @user3656168 If this closes the question then click on the check mark next to the post to accept it.